# Very old, very popular question, now closed

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question, [Saving Raphaël image as PNG on Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118134/saving-raphaeljs-image-as-png-on-internet-explorer), has been closed.

Please take a look at the view counter. Please, take a look at how old it is. Please, read it carefully - it's perfectly fine, technical, and was there for 2 years. And now it was closed (yeah, "on hold"), just by one guy, without any voting, without discussion, without any comment? What's going on?

Comment: This looks like a mishap. Voted to reopen

Comment: The `(on hold)` on this title makes it seem to be closed itself. It does not compute!

Comment: @brasofilo Sorry - I honestly don't understand your answer... Can you make it more clear?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why I put that one on hold, actually. Thank goodness for the community, and your constructive question about your question!

Comment: @mnowotka Your meta question included the phrase "`(on hold`)" in the title, which was confusing because it suggested this question is on hold, when it isn't. This is the point brasofilo was making.